# What is "Array to string error"?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

```
$data = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM user_pokemon_db WHERE user_id = '".$id."' ");
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($data))
{ 
 $pkmn_id = $rows['pkmn_id'];
 $path = mysql_query(" SELECT path FROM pokemons WHERE pk_id = '".$pkmn_id."' ");
 $poke = mysql_result($path, 0, "path");
 echo $poke; 
 echo "<br />";
 $level = $rows['level']; 
 echo $level;
 echo "<br />";
 $exp = $rows['exp']; 
 echo $exp;
```

This is my PHP code, its showing an error:
Array to string conversion in `C:\wamp\www\slots.php` on line 18

```
Line 18 is this:while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($data))
```

I haven't used any array?? but this used to work! but suddenly this error started coming??

Comment: Walk through the code in a debugger, inspect the variable values on each line...

Comment: what does `$id` consist?

Comment: How are you setting `$id` that is in you query? Is it possible that it is an array and not a string/integer.

Comment: Stop using `mysql_` functions and use PDO. Also don't interpolate variables into SQL queries.

Comment: $id is an array! I want to convert it into a variable!?? 
how can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if `$id` is an `array`, it seems that  it causes this problem.

```
$id = "'" . implode("', '", $id) . "'";
$data = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM user_pokemon_db WHERE user_id IN ({$id}) ");
```